# suppress text object if field value is null in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to suppress the text value in crystal by right clicking on the text object, selecting suppress and hitting the `x2` button and adding the formula

```
isnull(field)
```

When I look at the print preview the text is still there when the field value is null.

Comment: Do you mean _right-clicking on the text object, selecting Format Text..., checking the box beside Suppress, then hitting the `x-2` button_?

Comment: @dougp this is what I see as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the formula section, I changed the code from

```
isnull(field)
```

to

```
if {field} = "" then 
 true;
```

Comment: I've looked for this simple answer for awhile. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports a placeholder will still be on-screen when you hover over a suppressed field.  Since the field is NULL there really won't be a visual difference between NULL and suppressed fields.

Answer (score 0):

I can put my field in a section, right-click on the section (left margin of the editor) and select Section Expert...  In the Section Expert, I ensure the correct section is selected, then I can check the box for "Suppress Blank Section".

Answer (score 0):

Really all you needed was a pair of `{}` inside `()`.

Correct line of code to suppress anything in report if it's null is:

```
isnull({your_report_name.database_field_name})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
if ((trim({db.field}) = "") OR (IsNull({db.field}))) then
 >>>
else...
```

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)